# Dynamic Associative Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my application, I want to associate Country with its ID like this:

```
var Country = {
    'France': 15,
    'Canada': 26,
    'Italy': 32
};
```

My database return to me an Associative Array and I can easily take all data I want to use.
for the moment I use that but my "push" don't want to use my variable "pays" ...

```
var pays = data[i].pays.nomFR;
allPays = [];
allPays.push({pays : data[i].pays.id});
```

Comment: what id `data`  in the above code? Also, show the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
var pays = data[i].pays.nomFR;
allPays = new Array();
allPays[pays] = data[i].pays.id;
```

my push function was not the good one. That make exactly what I want!

:)

Comment: `allPays` should be an object `{}` not an array `[]`